# How to create/update bulk of products at a time programmatically

Tags: magento-1.9, ce-1.9.0.1, simple-product, programmatically

In the following code I have written to create a single simple product at a time, but I want to make a bulk creation of products at a time, can anyone help me in doing this?

```
Mage::app('default')->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
        $product->setAttributeSetId($attributeSetId);//ID of a attribute set named 'default'
        $product->setTypeId('simple');  //product type
        $product->setWebsiteIds(array(1));
        $product->setSku($itemjson->getSku($i)); //SKU
        $product->setName($itemjson->getName($i)); //product name
        $product->setWeight($itemjson->getWeight($i));
        $product->setUpdatedAt(strtotime('now'));
        $product->setStatus(1);//product status (1 - enabled, 2 - disabled)
        $product->setTaxClassId(4); //tax class (0 - none, 1 - default, 2 - taxable, 4 - shipping)
        $product->setVisibility(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH); //catalog and search visibility
        $product->setPrice($price); //price in form 11.22
        $product->setDescription($itemjson->getDesc($i));
        $product->setShortDescription($itemjson->getShortDesc($i)) ;
        $product->setStockData(array(
               'use_config_manage_stock' => 0, //'Use config settings' checkbox
               'manage_stock'=>1, //manage stock
               'min_sale_qty'=>1, //Minimum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart
               'max_sale_qty'=>1000, //Maximum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart
               'is_in_stock' => 1, //Stock Availability
               'qty' => $itemjson->getStock($i), //qty
                )
            );
        $catArray=$itemjson->getSimpleCat($i);
        $catKeys=array_keys($catArray);
        $product = self::manageAttr($product,$catArray);
        $product->setCategoryIds($categories);
        $product->save();
```

Comment: why are you not using the loop here?

Comment: There is no builk product creation. Use a loop. If you want to buil-update certain attributes, that is possible: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10355652/magento-bulk-update-attributes

Comment: Yes I tried looping here, but performance getting badly hit, If I loop around it, Only one item per second is getting saved, can anyone atleast help me how increase the performance

Answer (score 1):

maybe this instruction helps you.

```
$product->setIsMassupdate(true)->setExcludeUrlRewrite(true);
```

This may say Magento that is not necessary reindex tables on each product save.

Answer (score 1):

You can check this script [magento_dummy_simple_products_generation.php](https://gist.github.com/proxium/830fe06bf87083e5794a)

Basically it allows you to create a bulk set of simple products, you hard code the `PRODUCT_QTY` to set the desired number of generated simple products (by default 15) and the `CATEGORY_ID`.

Answer (score 1):

I think a real good way to go if you want quick bulk-inserting products is this free plugin [ApiImport](https://github.com/danslo/ApiImport):

It requires some programming skills, but in the end you'll be rocketing those product into your DB.

Combine with this [URL INDEX MODULE](https://github.com/EcomDev/EcomDev_UrlRewrite) from EcomDev (Also compatible with 1.7 - 1.9.2+) and reindexing is much quicker after an import.

Easy does it! ;)

This is how your code would look like:

```
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::init('admin');

$out = array();

$attributes = array(
    'sku',
    'weight',
    'website_ids',
    'status',
    'name',
    'desc' => 'description',
    'stock' => 'qty'
    //...
); // all the items you want to update

for($x->whatever_place_you_get_your_data_from() as $i)
{
    echo "$i\r";
    $i++;

    foreach($attr as $json_key => $attr)
    {
        switch($attr)
        {
            case 'website_ids':
            case 'status':
                $out[$i][$attr] = 1;
            break;
            case 'qty':
            case 'description':
                $out[$i][$attr] = $itemjson->{'get'.ucfirst($json_key)}($i);
            break;
            case 'name':
            case 'sku':
            case 'weight':
                $out[$i][$attr] = $itemjson->{'get'.ucfirst($attr)}($i);
            break;
            // etc...

        }
    }
}

$api = Mage::getModel('api_import/import_api');
$api->importEntities(
    $out,
    Mage_ImportExport_Model_Import_Entity_Product::getEntityTypeCode(),
    Danslo_ApiImport_Model_Import::BEHAVIOR_REPLACE
);
```